# If $f$ goes to infinity, prove it has a minimum

Tags: proof-writing, extreme-value-theorem

The question is:

> $f: A\to R$ is a continuous, real-valued function, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> If $f(x)\to\infty$ as $\|x\|\to\infty,$ show that $f$ attains a minimum.

Where I’ve gotten so far is I’ve written down the definition of this limit, and that tells that for all $M > 0$, there exists some $L > 0$ such that if $\|x\| > L$, then $f(x) > M$.

I can kind of see that this means that I need to take some $[-L, L]\subseteq A$ and use E.V.T. for compact sets here, and prove that $f(x)$ needs to be larger in $[-L, L]^c$, but I’m not really sure how to actually do any of that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely you must be assuming that $f$ is continuous. Otherwise consider $f(x) = |x|$ when $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 100$.

Comment: Show that the level sets $\{x | f(x) \le \alpha \}$ are compact.

Comment: @Drew Brady right, sorry, I forgot to add that *f* is continuous

Comment: Am I missing something.... the EVT only applies if the domain is a closed set.  If $A$ is an open interval, $f$ does not need to achieve a minimum.

Comment: You have to precise what $A$ is. For example, if $A = \mathbb Q$, then the map $f(x)=(x-\sqrt 2)^2$ satisfies the hypothesis, but has no minimum.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net we weren't given what A is, just that it's some subset of R^n

Comment: $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ has no minimum on $A= \{ 0 \}^c$, so the statement as such is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the claim is true.

It suffices to show that there exists a compact set $K$ such that
$$\inf_K f = \inf_{\mathbb{R}^n} f$$.

Indeed, then one can apply the extreme value theorem on $K$.

However, if there does not exist such $K$ for the above statement, it means that one can find a sequence $x_n$ with $\|x_n\|_ \to \infty$ but $f(x_n) \not \to \infty$. (For instance consider the ball of radius $r_n \to \infty$.)

Answer (score 1):

The result is false without further hypothesis on $A$. For example if $n=1$ and $A=\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$, then the map $f(x)=(x-\sqrt 2)^2$ satisfies the hypothesis of the question, but has no minimum.

Suppose that $A= \mathbb R^n$. Then according to the hypothesis on the limit of $f$ at $\infty$, it exists $R \gt 0$ such that for $\lVert x \rVert \ge R$, we have $\lvert f(x) \rvert \ge \lvert f(0) \rvert + 1$. On the compact disk $D$ centered on the origin and of radius $R$, $f$ is bounded and attains its minimum as it is supposed to be continuous. This minimum is also a global minimum.

Comment: What should the constraints on $A$ be?

Comment: @CSquared Not so easy to say... As: (1) it should include the [point at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity) in order for the limit hypothesis to make sense. (2) be complete to avoid the counterexample I mentioned. So in the end I don't see something more specific that being the whole space! For which I gave a proof.